# Pandas returns Dec 31 as max date, not the next year

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Why does this code return 12-31-2013 as the max date, and not 1-1-2014?
Something to do with how I'm reading the file?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', parse_dates=True)  
print df['simpleDate'].max()
```

output: **12/31/2013**

Table:

```
simpleDate
12/30/2013
12/31/2013
1/1/2014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't parse dates correctly. You should pass the column name instead of `True`.

```
In [9]: df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', parse_dates=['simpleDate'])

In [10]: df.max()
Out[10]: 
simpleDate   2014-01-01 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```